# How do i get quantity in a product_save_after event observer magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer

I have an observer that is observing **catalog_product_save_after**.  In this observer I want to get the product quantity.  but the **cataloginventory_stock_item** table is not updated until after the observer returns.  Is there some way to find the quantity entered in the "quantity" Field  for a brand new product?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `$productobj` after saving product from backend side so you can easily use `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in `M2`.

Right now you have to need develop new module for M2

Then Create this `events.xml` file in below path

`app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\etc\adminhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULENAME\Observer\Productsaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

And Create your observer file `Productsaveafter.php` in below path

app\code\YOUR_NAMESPACE\YOURMODULE\Observer\

```
<?php

namespace YOURNAMESPACE\YOURMODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $id = $product->getId(); //Get Product Id

        //Get Quantity
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        $stockData = $stockItem->getQty();
        // Get new Qty
        $_vendor_qty = $product->getVendorQty();
        $_on_hand_qty = $product->getOnHandQty();
        $totalQty = $_vendor_qty+$_on_hand_qty; //Add New Qty


        $stockItem->setQty($totalQty); //Set New Qty to Main Qty
        $stockItem->save();

    }   
}
```